# Assigning a datetime object as the url parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I want to give the value of Datetime type to url as parameter using date filter.

My url must be such: `/account/detail-of-cash-flow/2020-8-10`

This command: `{{item.date_field|date:'Y-m-d'}}` = '2020-8-10'. But, not working when i this commands implement to template url.

**template.html**

```
{% for item in cash_flow_data %}

    <tr class='clickable-row' data-href="{%  url 'account:detail_of_cash_flow' item.date_field|date:'Y-m-d' %}">     
        <td>{{ item.date_field }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.EUR }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.USD }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.GBP }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.TRY }}</td>
    </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
app_name = "account"
urlpatterns = [
    path('daily-cash-flow/', views.daily_cash_flow, name = "daily_cash_flow"),
    path('detail-of-cash-flow/<slug:slug>/', views.detail_of_cash_flow, name = "detail_of_cash_flow")
]
```

I hope I was able to explain my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your item model add method which will return format you need

```
class ItemModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_url_date(self):
        return self.date_field.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

and then in template you can use

```
<a href="{%  url 'account:detail_of_cash_flow' item.get_url_date %}">link</a>
```

upd:
according to your context you have several variants

1. update your context data

> ```
> context_flow_data = [
>   { 'url_date': item_data['date_field'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
>      'date': item_data['date_field'],
>      'USD': item_data['USD'],
>      'EUR': item_data['EUR'],
>      'GBR': item_data['GBR'],
>   } for item_data in cash_flow_data 
> ]
> ```

and then provide this data to your context
and in template use

```
<a href="{%  url 'account:detail_of_cash_flow' item.url_date %}">link</a>
```

second variant:
you can add line

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('detail-of-cash-flow/', views.detail_of_cash_flow, name = "detail_of_cash_flow")
    ...
]
```

and then in template use

```
<a href="{%  url 'account:detail_of_cash_flow' %}{{item.date_field|date:'Y-m-d'}}/">link</a>
```

Comment: This suggestion didn't work. I get:
Reverse for 'detail_of_cash_flow' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/detail\\-of\\-cash\\-flow/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Comment: `{{ item.get_url_date }}` = null

Comment: so what url do you want if date_field is null?

Comment: Ohhh sory. Remember now. My context data: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ZDbV9dmVSG/